# Java Regex Pattern Syntax Exception

Tags: java, regex, stringbuilder

I'm having problems with a Java Regex Pattern Syntax expression.

```
toCensor = toCensor.replaceAll((new 
   StringBuilder(("(?i)"))).append(word).toString(),
   String.copyValueOf(replace));
```

I get the following error:

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unmatched closing ')' 
   near index 4 (?i)!ick
```

no idea how to fix.... will give more code if needed

Comment: Which part of " Unmatched closing ')' near index 4 (?i) " is hard to understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't immediately see what's wrong with your regex code although I suspect the problem would be apparent if we knew the values for `toCensor` and `word`.  I've rewritten your code as follows:

```
String toCensor = "some sentence that uses frack word";
String word = "frack";
String replaceWith = "f#@!ck";
String regex = new StringBuilder("(?i)").append(word).toString();
toCensor = toCensor.replaceAll(regex, replaceWith);
```

So you are trying to run a regular expression across `toCentor` and do a case-insensitive match (that's the `(?i)` flag) looking for word.  One problem is that if `word` has any special regex characters, they will be treated as part of the pattern.  I think that's you bug.  For example if you try this:

```
String word = ")ick";
```

You'd get the error:

```
Unmatched closing ')' near index 4    (?i))ick
```

This is similar but not exactly what you are seeing.  You can turn off regex pattern compilation by wrapping the word in `"\Qword\E".  For example:

```
String regex = new StringBuilder("(?i)\\Q").append(word).append("\\E").toString();
toCensor = toCensor.replaceAll(regex, replace);
```

'\Q' in the pattern turns on "quoting" and `\E` is the end of it.  See also [`Pattern.quote()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29).  You can also fix this by doing better sanity checking of the input to make sure that they are whole words.  I suspect that `)` is not a proper character to be censored.

Answer (score 2):

This code is a mess.  Try splitting it into more manageable chunks by using variables.

```
StringBuilding regex = ....;
String replaceResult = toCensor.replaceAll(regex);
String appendResult = replaceResult.append(word);
...
```

This will make the code more readable and probably reveal your bug.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to match in your regex?

Your current regex says "match 0 or 1 case insensitively", you're not saying what to match. Is it a word? A number?

Also your code could do with some simplification, but lets deal with the regex first as that's where the problem lies.

2 lines of code will do it (based on existing parameters and constants in pastebin):

```
String regex = "(" + StringUtils.join(BADWORDS, "|") + ")";
String result = toCensor.replaceAll(regex, "*");
```

Comment: Sorry. The problem is that I found some code for a censor and I'm trying to deal with it but I have never used a regex before. I can post the code if you'd like. Don't even know if after fixing this it will work.

Comment: E.g. the regex ([a-z]?i) would match 0 or 1 character a-z or A-Z. You're missing the match criteria. So what is it you're trying to do?

Comment: @owlstead: I think the OP literally means "censor"; the code serves to replace a specified word with a specified replacement-string, and I think the specified word is actually supposed to be "censored". (If only all censors were so forthright about it!)

Comment: add the following snippet to remove characters that would require escaping:     toCensor = toCensor.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z-0-9]", "");